# IRegisteredObject and Process Crashed due to Unhanded Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

First of all I am using ASP.NET 4.0. Next I have wrapped IRegisteredObject inside BackgroundWorker with proper try/catch block.

```
public class BackgroundWorker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs a background task that is registered with the hosting environment
    /// so it is guaranteed to finish executing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The lambda expression to invoke.</param>
    public static void Run(Action action)
    {
        new IISBackgroundTask().DoWork(action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic object for completing tasks in a background thread
    /// when the request doesn't need to wait for the results 
    /// in the response.
    /// </summary>
    class IISBackgroundTask : IRegisteredObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs the object and registers itself with the hosting environment.
        /// </summary>
        public IISBackgroundTask()
        {
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by IIS, once with <paramref name="immediate"/> set to false
        /// and then again with <paramref name="immediate"/> set to true.
        /// </summary>
        void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            if (_task.IsCompleted || _task.IsCanceled || _task.IsFaulted || immediate)
            {
                // Task has completed or was asked to stop immediately, 
                // so tell the hosting environment that all work is done.
                HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes the <paramref name="action"/> as a Task.
        /// Any exceptions are logged
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="action">The lambda expression to invoke.</param>
        public void DoWork(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                // Log exceptions
                foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Logger.Log(innerEx);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(ex);
            }
        }

        private Task _task;
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = Loggers.Logger.Instance;
    }
}
```

and I am calling this as,

```
BackgroundWorker.Run(() => 
         // My Code            
);
```

But still my asp.net process crashes sometimes.

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7c78c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000a49d
Faulting process id: 0x2b90
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfb515a14c3320
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 9f0a3510-2164-11e4-822a-4040610959cf


Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException
Stack:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 11152

Exception: System.AggregateException

Message: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

InnerException: System.XXXX

Message: XXXX

StackTrace:   
   at MyMethod
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you start executing your `Task` inside `DoWork` using `Task.Factory.Startnew`, but then `DoWork` finishes executing, since it isn't awaited using `await`, or doesn't handle any exception using a continuation, which means `catch (AggregateException e)` is pretty useless.

You should register a continuation using [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void DoWork(Action action)
{
     _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action).ContinueWith((previousTask) => 
       {
           foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
           {
                Logger.Log(innerEx);
           }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Comment: `async`/`await` shouldn't be used on ASP.NET 4.0, but your second solution is good.

Comment: @StephanCleary I was looking around for the use of `async-await` with ASP.NET 4, could you elaborate more on why it shouldn't be used? Is it because of the marshaling of the request context with `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext`?

Comment: The `AspNetSynchronizationContext` had to be changed to properly support `async`/`await`. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx) states that `async` is undefined when using the old context. The old context is called `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext` in ASP.NET 4.5, and is the only one available pre-4.5.

Comment: @StephanCleary Right, i guess my assumption was right. Thank you